# Removing unwanted data from lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of varying length that I want to continuously up date with some new data.  So basically I want to add a new data point and remove any data out of a set range.  I have been playing around with this for a little bit now and haven't gotten anywhere that I can tell.  I was trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python) post as a reference, but apparently I don't under stand what is going on.  Below is a code snippet that is an example of what I have tried.

```
for i in range(0,100):
    n.append(i)
    n = [x for x in n if not (x-n[-1]>10)]
    print len(n)
```

Ideally n would only have the last 10 data points contained in it at any given time during the for loop.  I am sure that this is something basic that I am just not understanding, if you all could help me out I would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Edit: Example of the list n

```
[0]
[0, 1]
...
[89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 99]
```

Comment: "n would only have the last 10 data points" ... what exactly do you mean by last? most recent in terms of insertion?

Comment: can you give us an example of a list, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @KaustubhKarkare It would contain up to 10 of the most recent iterations (fewer before you hit 10), and then maintain a list of the 10 latest iteration numbers.  At the end n would be [90, 91, ... 99].

Comment: Alright ... then the answer I gave below will work.

Comment: @KaustubhKarkare That worked great!  Thanks!  I am also looking into the n.pop(0) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean that n should contain only the latest 10 data points inserted, you want:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    n.append(i)
    if len(n)>10: n[:] = n[1:]
    print len(n) # will never go above 10
```

Comment: `n[:] = n[1:]` can be replaced by `n.pop(0)`, as Colleen said.

Comment: what is the `n[:]` notation? Why not `n=n[1:]`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python/1208792#1208792

Answer (score 4):

Why not just `pop()` the list every time you append something, if `len>10`? If I'm understanding the question right.

```
for i in range(0,100):
    n.append(i)
    if len(n)>10:
       n.pop(0)
```

Comment: This works as well as Kaustubh Karkare's answer (n[:] = n[1:]), but the out put shows the popped number as well (outside of the list, I am printing `n` so I can see it).  Is this normal?

Comment: code, please! Not sure what you mean-- e.g. outside the loop could be before or after.

Comment: If I use your code with a `print n` after the `if` condition the last output looks like this `88` \n `[89, 90, ... 99]`.  The `88` is the popped value, and the list is `n`.  I was wondering if displaying the popped value is normal behavior.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you running this code in the interactive console? Because in that case, if the return values of statements aren't assigned to anything, they are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If I properly understand, you want to keep some variable number of elements in the list "n". Let's call that variable "m", so

```
for i in range(0,100):
    n.append(i)
    m = random.randint(1, 10)
    if len(n)>m:
        n = n[-m:]               # [-m:] defines the last m elements of n
    print len(n)
```

This should always print m in the end

Answer (score 0):

use [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with fast appends and pops:
and from python 2.7 up you can set maxlen.

```
from collections import deque

>>> d=deque([])
>>> for i in range(10):
...     d.append(i)
...     if len(d) > 3: d.popleft()
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
>>> d
deque([7, 8, 9])
```

Using maxlen:

```
>>> d = deque(range(5), maxlen=3)
>>> print d
deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
>>> print d.maxlen
3
```